# Google App Maker Table object only displays Date not DateTime

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a Calculated Model in the Google App Maker project. Where the date field is set as follows.

```
  calculatedModelRecord.PullDate = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
```

However when I display this calculated model in a Table or a Table Chart, only the Date part is displayed. The Time is missing. See screenshot below:

[image]

How do I make the Table/Table to display the Time as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date fields automatically come with an option to format the date according to preset choices or a custom property. To do this, you have to click on the text field in the editor, if you already set the text value to your datasource item, then on the dropdown click 'More Options' and then choose a format as described in the attached image.

[image: Date Field Format]

Comment: Thanks Markus. Looks like the Formatting option is available in the Table widget but not the Table Chart widget.